# non σ-algebra clarification

Tags: measure-theory

Let $S = (−∞, ∞)$ and $A_j = \{\text{all integers in } [−j, j]\}$  for $j = 1, 2, \ldots$.

Also, $F = \{A: A \text{ is finite or } A^c \text{ is finite}\}$, where $A^c$ means complement of $A$.
Clearly, $F$ is an Algebra on $S$.

Now, $\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^\infty A_j$ is the set $A$, say, of all integers. Thus A is infinite and furthermore so is $A^c$. Hence $A \notin F$, whereas $A_j\in F$ for all $j$.

Now, i read in a book that this proves that $F$ is not $σ$-algebra.
I think this conclusion is incorrect. The reason is as follows,

$\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{n}A_j = A_n$ for any $n$, because $[-2, 2] \supset [-1,1] $

So, $\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^\infty A_j = A$, as $n$ tends to $\infty$, must be a member of set $F$. Hence $F$ is an $σ$-algebra.

Please tell me if i am correct, if not where did i go wrong.

Comment: Note that $\displaystyle \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j$ is not defined as any sort of limit of $\displaystyle \bigcup_{j=1}^n A_j$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$. Rather $\displaystyle \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j$ is defined by saying $x \in \displaystyle \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty A_j$ if and only if $\exists j\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\}\  x\in A_j. \qquad$